# "Invalid_client" generating oAuth2 token for Adwords API

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I'm trying to set up oAuth2 for my google adwords api authentication method, however I'm running into an issue with getting my access and refresh tokens.

I ran the OAuth2TokenGenerator program, but it's throwing an error: "Invalid_client".

I've been using ClientLogin originally for my sandbox account. When I replaced the username/password with my live username/password it didn't work. So I thought I'd try oAuth2 - but that's not working either.

I'm wondering if I need to be using a specific email account for this. I'm using the email account I use to log in to Google Adwords. (Does it need to be the email account that actually created the adwords account originally?)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't using an email account that was a "Client Manager" and had "access to the user interface and  API".

Once I updated my client project and login info to use a Client Manager account, everything worked as expected.

Comment: How did you update the account type and permissions?

Comment: I think I created an MCC account then linked it to my existing account. https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704399?hl=en#create http://www.thomascreekconcepts.com/link-existing-adwords-account-mcc/